# Strange IE7 Spacing Appearing Under DIV

Tags: internet-explorer, css, cross-browser

http://www.downloadadeal.com.au/

The site above fine in all browsers except IE7 where a strange space appears between the content and the footer at the bottom of the layout? The two footer lines should match up. Has anybody experienced unexplained spacing before?

Answer (score 1):

No idea for sure, but you've a css rule 'div#page-content' with a height value set to "auto !important" which may be the problem since it is overriding a more specific rule named 'body#home div#page-content' that is trying to set the height to 636px. I can see you are trying to be pixel-accurate on the left and right sides of this page and that item might be foiling you?

Just something to look at.

Answer (score 0):

With IE, its a good idea to close your divs immediately after your content:
Instead of this:

```
<div>
  My Content
</div>
```

Do this:

```
<div>
  My Content</div>
```

I know, it messes up your nice indenting, but i find it works for me.

Comment: Looks like it could be it. I hate those spacing gremlins.

Answer (score 0):

You use the p tag in your footer. This may have a margin set on it. (The default for HTML4 is 1.12 em). Try adding margin-bottom: 0px; to the styles for the p elements in the footer.

You also have some stray space characters between the various div tags.

Answer (score 0):

The ‘margin-bottom’ on ‘#home-content’ collapses through the bottom of the ‘#page-content’ on IE, whereas on other browsers it correctly sits above the floats just after ‘#home-content’ instead.

Margin-collapsing is quite hard to get right, especially given IE's bugs, so it's often best avoided if you can (using padding-top/bottom instead).

In any case I would strongly advise you *not* to try to make your page heights an exact number of pixels like on this page. Any change in font settings/size will break it badly; for example if I zoom the text size up a bit half the text falls out of its containers, making the page entirely unusable.